# Deny access to C: to Edge

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-edge

Hello I post here cause i know adminsitrator will be happy to know it too! **im looking for prevent C: drive access with edge**. Do you have any idea , GPO ? ive ever blocked c: drive, hide c: drive, but i really wanna block access to it.
Thx a lot !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found how to do, its so simply in fact ! You only need to **download ADMX file** put it on your server, and active the GPO **"block these URL"** writing "C:". Then file://C: will be not available.
:)
source  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#urlblocklist